# Typescript: Get Type of Method Parameters from Generic

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to get the type of parameters of methods from a generic?

For example if I have:

```
interface Keys {
  create: any;
  ...
}

type MethodNames<T> = { [P in keyof Keys]: keyof T; }
```

Then is it possible to get the type of parameters of those Methods?

```
type MethodParams<T> = { [P in keyof Keys]: Parameters<T[???]>; }
```

[Playground Link to Relevant Code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzlAhgOwCYRAVRwSQBE4BfOAMymzgHIBjKATzBghoG4AoUSWROAIIAPYBADOAJQCmARwCuUsTADCENOWABzADSCR46WMhoxU0hSohaKfWI6dOUob3jA0MKVHIo6Z-Mqg5DABpKUYxRE44OAYpFA8ALjh0Ri5ozSkYAHk0KSSUtLgMmAEAG1L8tFSouDkwDHi85KrCjClSzKaCzhIHJxc4GGYzAKCAWUyACwgMMQAeABUAPjgAXkjogG0ABTg3OABrMIhyOH9AkLCxAF0ko8YTuAWuEi5HZ2h4IbARi4mYaYYbYoVAgCLrBA1HZ7NCHY6nc5BULhW61NAHNAQADuaE21xeb36n2SACMlKg6PA6KUUGIIgIyTAKTAFooYABRNAANzmAGVdAtdDgVpDomA5CTSsA6MkwMAkry3mKJVKZVBFBA5FBfPgMElyW5NEq4OLJdKYurGoRWElng5lWaZQxxlMZmIkqMMP9AfNeUtjWAqB5KVIMDE1OS5JToAAKFByhW6Z1e12zD1-VO+pYASg20UGk2AYgAdPHgGtZcBCtEAUXi8nvW6Kw3M9WC3X1WJNdqpLqK7WSxlcqgPIZuzqMDHs22B-XLR5rRB+4XB1Jh40AnEF6wY7PO+PexhpzVejVTarSeSfPAh54N-OpIuY-utRP9UzDdnbQGVeaUIzmSKTJgVBMQp3TF0ARmECUDBH9HSA9dRw1V9D3AuADTQTQ82idUYC1WEAAM3BgABaDwlFIgASBBUEwbA8CIKcSEIwpTwdC9aUYNAnQfMdULjWxpHkNlVHULQAH4kmEURJFkBQlDEjRNC-OBtksIspDmGSDEUYxTDmYURRqaI6AjKkH0bMN1hjXcV1LOVNlnFsoNmOctyka5kgiOR0UxHFc1pOAYxM-Ni3CsAQVg91mkYPFQtzVYVnU7BNO0oS9IjLSjOzYsSTcSdZzLY983DEx4Ei0DlzrYoYLBKd3MaNszPK5BFArFAsRQYALI8qyY3C4tKui3QbFk4SFJUNRlJK-M8IItqxDYnpOCAA)

Comment: The first example isn't even getting the methods... so I'm unsure about what you need.

Comment: Sorry it's getting the method names. I'll update the above for clarity. Perhaps there's a much better way of what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: How are you using the type `MethodNames`, though?

Comment: MethodNames is being used to call the named method of T. This is why I need the types of MethodParams.

Effectively I'm mapping methods to CRUD. This is to create an abstraction where I can call CRUD without knowing the name of the method itself in the Abstract Class.

Comment: Can you include all the relevant code in a [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?#code/Q)?

Comment: Added playground link to original post as url was too long.

Comment: erm, `Parameters<T[P]>` maybe?

Comment: P is the key mapping, not the key itself. e.g. 'create' maps to 'userControllerCreate'

Comment: Is [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WzPrrN) what you're looking for?  The only way to get the params is to know the actual mapping.  If it meets your needs I can write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing? (Please mention @jcalz in your reply to notify me)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/2887218/jcalz I played with your approach and was not able to get strong type check or hints. I opted to define the type at the concrete implementation layer to get the strictness. ty all!

Comment: "not able to get strong type check or hints"  Could you provide a [mre] that shows what the problem is?  It's nice that you've solved your own problem. Maybe you could write up an answer here that shows the solution (it's perfectly acceptable to answer your own Stack Overflow question)?

Comment: Revisited with a fresh mind this morning. @jcalz solution is excellent which I've shortened [here](https://tsplay.dev/mbQVdN) for clarity (original verbosity was my fault). Thank you @jcalz!

The thing I'm having difficulty with in my particular use case is that when using an API generated via [Open API Generator Typescript Axios](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator) the inference seems to evaluate to never. 

TS2322 tells me I'm missing the CreateDto in the array, but if I add, TS2322 says Type 'Create' is not assignable to type 'never'

Comment: What do you want me to do here? I could post my solution as an answer, or you could post an answer, or you could [edit] your question if it needs to clarify some requirements the current solutions are missing, or you could post a new question if you have followups.  This looks like a followup question to me, since you've moved past the "how do I express this type" and onto "how do I implement some subclass". Please let me know how to proceed (mention @jcalz to notify  me)

Comment: @jcalz you're absolutely right it's a follow up and belongs elsewhere. Would love to "accept" your solution. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Okay I'll write up an answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can imagine this working is if `MethodParams` is not only [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in `T`, the type of the underlying API, but also in `M`, the particular `MethodNames<T>` appropriate for `T`.  And that could look like this:

```
type Keys = "create" | "getOne" | "getAll" | "update" | "delete"

export type MethodNames<T> = {
  [K in Keys]: keyof T;
};

export type MethodParams<T, M extends MethodNames<T>> = {
  [K in Keys]: T[M[K]] extends (...args: infer P) => any ? P : never;
};
```

(Note that I make `Keys` just a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of string [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) instead of making it an object type with values of type `any` that we ignore.)

So `MethodParams<T, M>` iterates over the keys in `Keys` and then looks up each key in `M` to get the key of `T` we want to probe for parameters.  That is, if `K` is a member of `Keys`, we want to get the parameters from what we hope is a function type at `T[M[K]]`. We use [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) to get that.

---

Let's test to see that it works.  First I'll write a helper function to verify that a proposed method mapper works for a particular type `T`:

```
const methods = <T, M extends MethodNames<T>>(api: T, methods: M) => methods;
```

And now I'll make up a fake api:

```
interface SomeData {
  id: number,
  a: string,
  b: number,
  c: boolean
}
interface SomeApi {
  change(id: number, data: Partial<SomeData>): SomeData,
  destroy(id: number): boolean
  grab(id: number): SomeData | undefined,
  grabbingSpree(): SomeData[],
  make(data: Omit<SomeData, "id">): SomeData,
}
declare const someApi: SomeApi;
```

Here's the method mapper:

```
const someApiMethods = methods(someApi, {
  create: "make",
  getOne: "grab",
  getAll: "grabbingSpree",
  update: "change",
  delete: "destroy"
})
```

And now I can finally try `MethodParams`:

```
type SomeApiMethodParams = MethodParams<SomeApi, typeof someApiMethods>;
/* type SomeApiMethodParams = {
    create: [data: Omit<SomeData, "id">];
    getOne: [id: number];
    getAll: [];
    update: [id: number, data: Partial<SomeData>];
    delete: [id: number];
} */
```

Looks good.  The type of `SomeApiMethodParams` is what we expect it to be.

---

Oh, and this also means that any class or type that needs to compute `MethodParams` will need to be generic in the appropriate `MethodNames` type.  For example, your `AbstractTestEnv` class would be augmented with another type parameter:

```
export abstract class AbstractTestEnv<S, T, U, M extends MethodNames<S>> {
  public api: S;       
  public createDto: T;
  public crudMethods: M;    
  protected constructor(api: S, crudMethods: M) {
    this.api = api;
    this.crudMethods = crudMethods;
    this.createDto = this.generateCreateDto(this.resourceId);
  }   
  public abstract generateCreateDto(resourceId: string): T;
  public abstract getParams(): MethodParams<S, M>;
  /* snip */
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-tYeFefZkWubxTKw1+EHTp60S+oigXldV2WIHhLXObFt7RLdbtNgca7Dp+s7RpN8aIpgdTLj3RYHP9zSblM12vvdu7FcFqRhbt8Xu3epiE2GbcYCeqYAANJhgABaYIlDzgASBBUEwbA8CIPcSCzvWI8Ns6xEYNBfst+PRbFWxpHkKbVHULRSUWYRREkWQFCUfuNE0bsTksEmpE6EeDEUYxTE6HBdtTpHgPcwJggcgZ4Q1qWyYlEZeaZ1TpctqFBrgGcljQCAAHc0AJe-4SStzkURMAnMuIsYkx5v6Kn6HPbAC8l7d1XkyRem9KyIkYhgE+tNzq62-kBZk-8lLy1PqREOe46aWyplg+A7MKYvxQHePeeQHJImRDgjSugbCjx7hPFQahp4YPCunTO90xD1zDEAA)